# How to minimize a weighted sum of RMSE-like terms?

Tags: optimization, modeling, nonlinear-programming

I am trying to solve the following problem: \begin{align}
\min&\quad f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_ix_i} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}{b_i\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{m}{\left(y_{i,j}-x_i\right)^2}}}\\\text{s.t.}&\quad
x_{i+1}\geq x_i \quad\forall i \in \{1,\dots,n-1\} \\&\quad
y_{i,j} \geq x_i \quad\forall (i,j) \in \{1,\dots,n\} \times \{1,\dots,m\} \\&\quad
y_{i,j} \geq c_j \quad\forall (i,j) \in \{1,\dots,n\} \times \{1,\dots,m\} \\&\quad
x_i \geq 0 \quad\forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\}
\end{align}

The parameters $a_i$, $b_i$ and $c_j$ are all positive numbers.

The problem is not quadratic because of the $\sqrt{\cdot}$ functions in the objective. Therefore I believe mathematical programming solvers will be unable to solve this problem. Are local search methods the way to go here or is there a way to reformulate my problem that makes it easier to solve? If it's the former, are there off-the-shelf tools that I can use ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The square root terms are two-norms and the rest of the problem is linear. Therefore, this can be solved by a solver capable of handling Second Order Cone Problems (SOCP).  Among such solvers are CPLEX, Gurobi, Mosek, SeDuMi, SDPT3, and KNITRO, among others.

This problem is convex, and can be solved with such solvers to global optimality.

This problem can be expressed as a SOCP by using an epigraph formulation of norm. That is, replace the norm terms by $t_i$, and introduce constraints, $\text{norm}(...) \le t_i$.

If a convex optimization modeling tool such as CVX, YALMIP, CVXPY, or CVXR is used, this reformulation can be handled automatically (under the hood) by the tool.

In CVX, the formulation would look like

```
cvx_begin
variables x(n) y(n,m)
minimize(a'*x + b'*norms(y - repmat(x,1,m)),2,2)
<incorporation of linear constraints left as straightforward exercise>
cvx_end
```

making use of `norms`, which is a CVX function which computes a vector of norms at once from a matrix and produces a vector output. But this can be done using loops using plain old `norm` instead.

> help norms
>
> norms   Computation of multiple vector norms.
>       norms( X ) provides a means to compute the norms of multiple vectors
>       packed into a matrix or N-D array. This is useful for performing
>       max-of-norms or sum-of-norms calculations.
>
> ```
> All of the vector norms, including the false "-inf" norm, supported
> by NORM() have been implemented in the norms() command.
>   norms(X,P)           = sum(abs(X).^P).^(1/P)
>   norms(X)             = norms(X,2).
>   norms(X,inf)         = max(abs(X)).
>   norms(X,-inf)        = min(abs(X)).
> If X is a vector, these computations are completely identical to
> their NORM equivalents. If X is a matrix, a row vector is returned
> of the norms of each column of X. If X is an N-D matrix, the norms
> are computed along the first non-singleton dimension.
>
> norms( X, [], DIM ) or norms( X, 2, DIM ) computes Euclidean norms
> along the dimension DIM. norms( X, P, DIM ) computes its norms
> along the dimension DIM.
>
> Disciplined convex programming information:
>     norms is convex, except when P<1, so an error will result if these
>     non-convex "norms" are used within CVX expressions. norms is
>     nonmonotonic, so its input must be affine.
> ```